# how to use distinct in android room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I am using android room instead of sqllite. In my application database column have multiple records. For example my column name is country. The values are

- India
- Germany
- Qatar
- Germany
- Ireland
- Saudi
- America
- Germany
- Africa
- Qatar
- Germany

I want the result is

- India
- Germany
- Qatar
- Ireland
- Saudi
- America
- Africa

The **Qatar** and **Germany** cames more than times. I want sort out to single item. I have used `SELECT DISTINCT name from country`. But it showing errors . My code is shown on below.

**CountryDao.java**

```
@Dao
public interface CountryDao {
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void addCountry(Country country);  
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT name from country")
public List<Country> getCountry();
}
```

**Country.java**

```
@Entity
public class Section {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Section(int id, String name){
    this.setId(id);
    this.setName(name);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

It's shows the error is 
The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [id] in com.android.db.Country even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [name]

**AppDatabase.java**

```
@Database(entities = {Country.class}, version = 5, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase{
private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;
public abstract ClassDao classDao();
public abstract SessionDao sessionDao();
public abstract SectionDao sectionDao();
public static AppDatabase getDatabase(Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
       INSTANCE =
                Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, "edumiadatabase").fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

public static void destroyInstance() {
    INSTANCE = null;
}
}
```

In my activity getting data by adding this code. ``List co = database.countryDao().getCountry();

Comment: You do not have code for your `Country` class. You have code for a `Section` class.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got the answer by making changes
I have change the query in **CountryDao.java** . rewrite the query to

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT name from country")
public List<String> getCountry();
```

Then call in the activity like this.

```
 List<String> co = database.countryDao().getCountry();
    for(int i=0; i<co.size();i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "country:" + co.get(i));
    }
```

It's the problem is in my code get the list by object but i want it in strings. Thanks for all frienda.

Comment: The query in the answer and question is the same! What you did different?

Comment: The origin was `List<Country> getCountry();`, and then change to `List<String> getCountry();`. I think it returns List<String> because of specifying a field with `name`

Answer (score 1):

List items = database.countryDao().getCountry();
List of strings 
 **use for loop here to iterate**

Comment: ys, id is primary key

Comment: you are try to returning list of country  objects but your sql query is for list of strings


https://pastebin.com/8UsfdeSK

Comment: can u tell me the query to use distinct

Comment: your query is correct 
your aim is to get list of name strings  but your code seems to list of objects
and this is error check my pastebin

Comment: I want the list. how to print on list.

Comment: List co = database.countryDao().getCountry();
as you mentioned 
List<String> items  = database.countryDao().getCountry();
use for loop here to iterate